# Jqplot Date axis renderer

Tags: jquery-validate, jqplot

I have to display dates on x-axis according to dates coming in following code:

```
for(i=0;i<ticks1.length;i++)
{
   ptt.push([ticks1[i],data1[i]]);    
   ntt.push([ticks1[i],data2[i]]);    
}
```

WHERE ticks1 contain dates.

I want to draw dateaxis chart in jqplot

Comment: What are ptt and ntt? Can you please provide more code, jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) preferably, so we can see what you did so far?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing var in your for loop, forgive me if I'm wrong. I think your ptt and ntt is two different series and if you want the code for this type check the 3rd example in the following link:- http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php.

you will have to add the data[] thing like this

```
var ptt = [];
```

for (var i=0;i

var ntt = [];
  for (var i=0;i

and ..

```
  var plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [ntt, ptt],
{ //option string});
```

also you need to add the data render too

```
title:'Default Date Axis',
axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}},
series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
```

cheers!..